# Access to Word: student listing via VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

I have the following student table in Microsoft Access:

```
name | email_address
--------------------
Student 1 | student1@example.com
Student 2 | student2@example.com
Student 3 | student3@example.com
```

I also have a Microsoft Word document like this:

```
List of students

Name: __________________________________
Email address: ___________________________________
```

What I'd like to accomplish, via VBA code, is to create a new Microsoft Word document, using the former document as a template, so that the output is as follows:

```
List of students:

Name: Student 1
      _________
Email address: student1@example.com
               ____________________

Name: Student 2
      _________
Email address: student2@example.com
               ____________________

Name: Student 3
      _________
Email address: student3@example.com
               ____________________
```

It is important to note here that **I cannot assume that the table only holds 3 students, as in the example above**; it may have 4, 5, 6... Could be even a billion of them!

I'd like to achieve this via VBA code, but have no clue as to how it can be done. So far, the only code I have is:

```
Private Sub btnOpenDocument_Click()
    OpenStudentListing
End Sub

Private Sub OpenStudentListing()
    Dim appword As Word.Application
    Dim doc As Word.Document

    On Error Resume Next
    Error.Clear
    Set appword = GetObject(, "word.application")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set appword = New Word.Application
        appword.Visible = True
    End If

    filePath = ExtractTemplate(Student_Listing)
    If IsNull(filePath) Then Exit Sub
    Set doc = appword.Documents.Open(filePath)
    'The document opens just fine, but now what?
End Sub
```

Is this even possible to accomplish? If so, how?

Comment: Why do you want to use VBA? This would be so easy with the mailmerge function in word (google it).

Answer (score 0):

Save the docx as a dotx (true Word template that can hold additional things you need).

Create a Building Block entry from the text you want to repeat in the document (where you want to insert the data) and save it IN THE TEMPLATE. Save and close the template.

Use the Documents.Add method rather than Documents.Open in order to base a new document on the template.

Loop your records and insert the Building Block for each one.

(Note that my answer bases on the information you give, which is limited. It may well be missing some puzzle pieces because I have no idea what you do and do not know. There are lots of examples on the Internet for this kind of thing where you can find more detail...)

Answer (score -1):

Why not make it a report, and from the report make what you want (Excel, Word, PDF ...). And the reason to be hidden you can make the output directly to word of course by Macro or by VBA when click the command.